# How to read an excel file with no header in R

Tags: r

I have an excel file which do not have any column header. The data are starting in the first row (A1).

How is it possible to reade the file now in R without having first row as header in R.

[image]

The first row is always set as header, but I don't want it as header

```
library (readxl)
read_excel("Myexcel.xlsx", na="NA")
```

Comment: Does `read_excel("Myexcel.xlsx", na="NA", col_names=FALSE)` solve your problem?

Comment: @B.ChristianKamgang Thanks alot. Is it posisble to give the column a name? It is renamed to ...1 and ...2 I want ot have names for the column header

Comment: Yes, you can replace `col_names=FALSE` with the vector containing the column names ( `col_names=c("varname1", "varname2", ..., "varnamen")`)

Comment: you can also rename your data frame columns afterwards with `colnames(your_data_frame) = c('name1', 'name2')`